# How can I prove this solution is valid for w in (-infinity to +infinity)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$w = \frac{(ab - d) }{c - a - b}$$

I have to solve the above equation for variables `c` and `d` if `w` can be any number from $$w \in (-\infty, +\infty)$$

If we set `w = 0, then w = 1`  we can solve for `c and d`

$$0 = ab - d$$
$$d = ab$$
$$c = a + b$$

Now if I can substitute the values to check the solution for `w = 1`
$$c - a - b = ab - d$$
Substituting c, $$a + b - a - b = ab - d$$
$$0 = ab - d$$
$$d = ab$$

I know that my solution is true for both `w = 0 and w = 1` but how can I prove that my solution is true for $$w \in (-\infty, +\infty)$$

Comment: if $c=a+b$, you get a little explosion there...

Comment: Is w allowed in the solution to avoid division by zero? So, perhaps division by zero is acceptable in this restricted case.

Comment: No, w is not allowed in the solution.

Comment: oh, okay. Then your answer must be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about d = ab-w;
           c = 1+a+b;
c=a+b results in division by 0.
I was trying to find a solution without division by zero.

Here's another stab at it. If (ab-d)/(c-a-b) can be any number, let it equal x.
x/1 = (ab-d)/(c-a-b)
cross multiply to get:
ab - d = (c -a -b)x; 
ab - d = cx - ax -bx; 
put c and d on the right and a and b on the left
ab + ax + bx = cx +d; 
(a + b)x + ab = cx + d . 
Now, if x can be any real number, then
a + b has to equal c  and
ab has to equal d.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I'm not sure what your statement/question is?

Comment: c = a+b results in the denominator equal to zero. If we allow division by zero, then your answer is correct.

Comment: Also, how did you figure out that d = ab - w and c = 1 + a + b? There is only one statement so I was unable to use a systems of equation solution.

Comment: To make the right side equal w, let the right side = w/1 . Then the numerator has to equal ab-d and the denominator has to equal 1. Then solve for the desired variables. It is a tricky question, because if you look at it your way, it is true that w can be any real number. It didn't say that w was not allowed in the answer, so I suggested my answer.

Comment: I hadn't thought of solving it that way at all.  I've decided to give you the best answer because you suggested a method that I hadn't thought of at all, which I'm sure could be useful in other math questions- Additionally, I never stated that w had to be removed from the equation.  Thanks!

Comment: Jason, are you referring to my last paragraph. That type of reasoning comes in handy sometimes. My original suggestion sometimes cannot be done. That is, 3/6 equals 4/8 , but 3≠4 and 6≠8. But, IF you know the denominators are equal, then the numerators have to be equal as well.

Answer (score 0):

After coming back from a break and just looking at my question I figured out the solution.

$$w(c - a - b) = (ab - d)$$
$$w(a + b - a -b) = ab - d$$
$$0 = ab - d$$

$$ab = d$$

Therefore, it is true for all values